# Export dataset with predicted target - Python

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, training, confusion-matrix

I've this code (part of predictive model):

```
training_features, test_features, training_target, test_target, = train_test_split(df.drop(['target'], axis=1),
                                              df['target'],
                                              test_size = .3,
                                              random_state=12)
    coef_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", random_state = 100, max_depth = 3, min_samples_leaf = 5)
    coef_gini.fit(training_features, training_target)

    y_pred = coef_gini.predict(test_features)
    y_pred
```

How can I export my dataset with the predictive value in order to create a confusion matrix to determine the False Positive value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for generating Confusion Matrix, then you can try using this command:

```
#for generating confusion matrix    
sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, sample_weight=None)
```

If you are just looking for binding predicted and actual values, you can use this command

```
#For Arrays you can use this
numpy.concatenate() 

#for dataframe you can use this
DataFrame.append(other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False)[source]
```

for better understaning you can go through this [Link-1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html),[Link-2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html),[Link-3](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)